# Deadlock caused due to multiple inserts in a transaction

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have a sp which has insert statements like this:

```
begin transaction

insert into table1
insert into table2
.
.
.
insert into table n

commit transaction
```

This all is fine as long as the sp is not called concurrently. However when the sp is called concurrently I face deadlock issue sometimes on the primary key of the first table.

Comment: Are you locking the table during the insertion?

Comment: All I am doing is running the code in a transaction as you can see in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

There are a mirriad ways this can deadlock. Post the actual deadlock graph (the **actual** xml, not the picture of the dealock!).

If you truly have nothing but inserts (no reads) then the most likely cause is foreign key constraints. Post the exact schema definition (all table definition, all index definition, all constraints, including primary keys and foreign keys). BTW, if you have any trigger defined then all bets are off as the deadlock could be caused by arbitrary trigger code.

Comment: You are right. There are foreign keys which use the primary key of the first table. Can't reproduce the issue at the moment. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: A cheap way out is to disable the FK constraints during your data load windows, and enable them back after the ETL. See [ALTER TABLE ... WITH NOCHECK ...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx). If the tables are large enabling back the FK constraints can take some time, as it has to be validated.

Comment: Another relatively cheap way out is to use versioning (snapshot isolation or enable read committed snapshot) see [Row Versioning-based Isolation Levels in the Database Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177404.aspx)

Comment: Will it be safe to disable FK constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set for your db some reliable isolation level, like ReadCommitted?

Comment: Didn't set. But i believe ReadCommited is the default one.